# EF4 DbContext LINQ query where entity not marked for deletion

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

I can't seem to find a way to (wondering if it is indeed possible) to perform a LINQ query on the DBContext giving only items that are not marked for deletion.

e.g.

```
// Mark one or more items in the DBContext for deletion.
(from di in DbContext.DeliveryItems where di.Id == myId select di).ToList().ForEach(di => this.Context.DeleteObject(di));
```

Can I then perform a query that will ignore the deleted objects (without of course having to fire a SaveChanges())?

```
decimal? weight = (from s in this.Context.Stocks
                   where di.Id == myId
                   select s.GrossWeight).Sum();
```

i.e. I only want the sum of weights for stock entities that have not been marked for deletion.

**EDIT:** Couldn't get ChangeTracker() reference working so ended up doing the following...

```
List<int> deletedDeliveryItems = this.Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Deleted)
                                 .Where(x => x.EntityKey.EntitySetName == "DeliveryItems")
                                 .Select(x => ((DeliveryItem)x.Entity).Id).ToList();

decimal? sumWeightOfDeletedDeliveryItems = (from s in DbContext.Stocks
                                            where deletedDeliveryItems.Count > 0 &&
                                            deletedDeliveryItems.Contains(s.Id)
                                            select s.GrossWeight).Sum();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var delete = (from di in DbContext.DeliveryItems where di.Id == myId select di).ToList();

delete.ForEach(di => this.Context.DeleteObject(di));

decimal? weight = (from s in this.Context.Stocks
                   where !delete.Select(di => di.Id).Contains(s.SomeId)
                   select s.GrossWeight).Sum();
```

If you for some reason need to get the deleted items from the `DbContext`. You can do this:

```
var deleted = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
               .Where(x => x.State == System.Data.EntityState.Deleted)
               .Select(x=> x.Entity).ToList();
```

Comment: Ah excellent idea, couldn't see the wood for the trees! I'll go with the list of id's for now, like you imply, there's no need to query the context again. Thank you!

Comment: I'm just wondering what I will probably try (rather than creating a list and moving that across methods etc), is to meld the 'weight' query into one with the ChangeTracker query.